# How to get rid of the __actions__ entry in the CrudRestController's response?

Tags: rest, turbogears2

I'm subclassing the CrudRestController to implement an REST interface. It works fine, but the response dict contains an `__actions__` entry which contains some html code that I really don't want in my response.

According to the TableFiller class' docstring something like this should work:

```
class ProcessController(CrudRestController):
    model = Process
    #...
    class table_filler_type(TableFiller):
        __model__ = Process
        __actions__ = False
```

But the page always throws an `AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute '__actions__'`

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the inline docs, the correct way seems to be:

```
class table_filler_type(TableFiller):
    __model__ = Process
    __omit_fields__ = ['__actions__', ]
```